# Most efficeint way to regulate radiator system

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Ok it's hard to put the question into the question bar. I have a central heating system that runs off a stove, I burn peat but that's irrelevant assume the fire is at a constant temperature. So the pipes heat up as the fire burns and a pump will activate once the pipes have reached a temperature that I set on a thermometer. The water is then pumped around the system and sheds heat from the radiators. If I set it to a lower temperature it will turn on quicker and for longer but the water being pumped will be cooler, If I set it to a higher temperature the pump will come on later and won't run for as long but the water will be hotter and so the radiators will radiate more heat. In terms of air temp, the goal of all these pipes, which is more efficient?

What do the laws of thermodynamics suggest is more efficient at dispersing heat, low temperature for longer or higher temperature for a shorter period. No need to *engineer* the system just an summary of what the maths tell us please.